# Difference b/w Get-AzureAutomationConnection VS Get-AzureRMAutomationConnection?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

What is the difference between Get-AzureAutomationConnection and Get-AzureRMAutomationConnection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Get-AzureAutomationConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/get-azureautomationconnection?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) is **[Azure Service Management module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/servicemanagement/overview?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)**  while [Get-AzureRMAutomationConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.automation/get-azurermautomationconnection?view=azurermps-6.7.0) is **[Azure Resource Management module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/powershell-azure-resource-manager)**.

In short, they belong to different powershell modules.

Comment: And the first talks with Azure Service Management API (the old one) while the second talks with Azure Resource Management API (the current one).

Comment: So is it like Azure Service Management API is not much in use these days and

Comment: when to use Azure Service management and when to use Azure Resource Management

Comment: Refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/deprecating-service-management-apis-support-for-azure-app-service/).

Comment: Thank you so much ! Joey. This is really very helpful.